# Conditional inner join in SQL Server using CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I'm trying to join 3 tables.

My first table is `Order_Header` with primary key `Id` and two foreign keys `User_Id` to `User` table, and `Guest_Id` to `Guest` table.

If in `Order_Header` table the value for `Guest_Id` is 0, I want to do an `inner join` with the `User` table, and if the value for `User_Id` is 0, I want to `join` with the `Guest` table.

How can I achieve that?

```
Select 
    Order_No, [user].Id, [User].Email, [Guest].Id, Guest.Email 
from 
    Order_Header OH
left join 
    [User] on OH.User_Id = [User].Id and OH.User_Id <> 0
left join 
    [Guest] on OH.Guest_Id = [Guest].Id and OH.User_Id = 0
where
    (case OH.User_Id 
        when 1 then [User].Email 
        else [Guest].Email 
     end as SomeField)
```

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR instead of case expressions in WHERE and ON clauses.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CASE in selection not in condition:

```
Select Order_No, 
  [user].Id,  
  [Guest].Id, 
  CASE WHEN OH.User_Id = 0 THEN [Guest].Email 
       ELSE [User].Email, 
from Order_Header OH
  left join [User] ON OH.User_Id = [User].Id
  left join [Guest] ON OH.Guest_Id = [Guest].Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is almost correct, you're only missing a couple `coalesce` in the `select` instead of that `where` clause (which is syntactically wrong)

```
Select  Order_No,
        coalesce(usr.Id, [Guest].Id) as someID
        coalesce(usr.Email, Guest.Email) as someEmail
from    Order_Header OH
left join
        [User] as usr
ON      OH.User_Id = usr.Id AND OH.User_Id <> 0
left join
        [Guest] as gst
ON      OH.Guest_Id = gst.Id AND OH.User_Id = 0
```

This way you will only have one `ID` column and one `Email` column, each populated with the values from `User` if available, or from `Guest` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the following table definitions

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Guest](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Guest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order_Header](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [User_Id] [int] NULL,
    [Guest_Id] [int] NULL,
    [Order_No] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Order_Header] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order_Header]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Header_Guest] FOREIGN KEY([Guest_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Guest] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order_Header] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Header_Guest]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order_Header]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Header_User] FOREIGN KEY([User_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order_Header] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Header_User]
GO
```

You may use the following query to get your results

```
SELECT [dbo].[Order_Header].[Order_No],
ISNULL([dbo].[User].Id, [dbo].[Guest].id) as 'Id',
ISNULL([dbo].[User].Email, [dbo].[Guest].Email) as 'Email'
FROM [dbo].[Order_Header]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[User]
ON [dbo].[Order_Header].User_Id = [dbo].[User].Id
AND [dbo].[Order_Header].User_Id <> 0
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Guest]
ON [dbo].[Order_Header].Guest_Id = [dbo].[Guest].Id
AND [dbo].[Order_Header].Guest_Id = 0
```